# Python format string containing \n and \t

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, line

Below is the string content, which I needed to format:

Input:

```
input = 'This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs'

print(input) #This results like below,

'This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs'
```

But the Expected Output:

```
'This is line_number_1 
    This is second line with a tab 
        This is third line with two tabs'
```

The expected should be a string and not list of lines using Python

Comment: what is your question? if you print the input you will get the output.

Comment: when i store it inside a string, I can still see the \n and \t

Comment: `input` is a built-in function, don't use as name. Again, when you `print(input)` it will produce the desired output, not what you show

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up the notions of *output* and *representation*. If you want to see *output* then you need to *output* the data, that is, use a `print()` call. Like this:

```
>>> s = 'This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs'
>>> print(s)
This is line_number_1 
     This is second line with a tab 
         This is third line with two tabs
```

If you simply evaluate `s` you will see Python's default internal representation, which is the same as your input:

```
>>> s
'This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs'
```

Comment: You're mixing up representations. Python's internal representation of a string is closer to what you see with `print` than what you get if you type `s` at an interpreter prompt. Typing `s` at an interpreter prompt calls `repr` on the string, and calling `repr` on a string builds a new string representing Python source code that would evaluate to the original string. In other words, it's a source code representation of the string, not Python's internal representation.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I deliberately used "Python's internal representation" instead of `repr()` because it was evident that OP would not have understood that. It is a very useful phrase when a beginner wants "to get rid of the backslashes in my string" or to "remove the redundant `Decimal()` in my output". Sometimes it is more important to explain things in terms a beginner will understand than to be strictly accurate. Think of it as "internal to the Python code" rather than "internal to the underlying CPython interpreter".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting a single slash, put double slashes. Like:

```
input = 'This is line_number_1 \\n \\t This is second line with a tab \\n \\t\\t This is third line with two tabs'
print(input)
```

If you run this code, you get the output as:

```
This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs
```

But if you want tabs, then write only with 1 slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the print statement for removing the escape sequences from the input

```
input = 'This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs'
print(input)
```

But if you want the Quotations to be there after printing the input add extra escape sequences as given below:

```
input = '\'This is line_number_1 \n \t This is second line with a tab \n \t\t This is third line with two tabs\''
print(input)
```